# Llaves o índices asociativos inesperados en función que tiene array_merge

Tags: php

¿Por qué tiene ese comportamiento (no esperado) la función `array_push_assoc()` agregando algunos elementos con índice numérico? Si fuera del FOR sí crea el elemento asociativo como se espera.

#`array_push_assoc()` es como el `array_push()` pero para crear arrays asociativos!!!

```
    function array_push_assoc(array &$arrayDatos, array $values){
    $arrayDatos = array_merge($arrayDatos, $values);
    }
```

#función donde se implementa la fn `array_push_assoc()`

```
    function multiplicacionSecuencial(int $multiplicando, int $inicio=0, int $fin=10):array{
        $array=[];
        array_push_assoc($array,["multiplicando"=>$multiplicando]);
        for ($i = $inicio; $i <= $fin; $i++){
            $multiplicador = strval($i);
            $producto = strval($multiplicando * $i);
            array_push_assoc($array,[$multiplicador=>$producto]);
        }
        #verificando el buen funcionamiento fuera del FOR:
        array_push_assoc($array,["clave"=>"valor"]);
        #comprobando el comportamiento de la funcion con un elemento indexado:
        array_push_assoc($array,["otraCosa"]);
        return $array;
    }
```

#implementado:

```
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump(multiplicacionSecuencial(5,9,10));
#se esperaba que el primer elemento de informacion sobre de que numero quiero la tabla, y los demás elementos cual seria el multiplicador y su producto respectivo
# ej: ["9"]=> string(2) "45" en su lugar se lee [0]=>string(2) "45" =/
/*
array(5) {
  ["multiplicando"]=>
  int(5)
  [0]=>
  string(2) "45"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "50"
  ["clave"]=>
  string(5) "valor"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "otraCosa"
}
*/
```

Comment: Se cambió el título por uno más descriptivo al problema para que sea mejor indexado por el sitio y sirva a otros usuarios. Puedes editar la pregunta y modificarlo si no te satisface.

Answer (score 0):

De forma simple, tu problema *no es resolvible*. El tema está en que PHP al ver una llave tipo *string* con un contenido entero válido, automáticamente lo convierte a entero y no se puede evitar. La [documentación de Array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php) reza:

> Strings que contiene un decimal válido integer, a menos que el número
> esté precedido por un signo +, será amoldado al tipo integer. Por
> ejemplo, la llave "8" será en realidad almacenado como 8. Por otro
> lado "08" no será moldeado, ya que no es un entero decimal válido.

Entonces al hacer [array_merge()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php) se le aplica el refactorizado al índice por ser numérico, empezando por `0`, luego `1`, ... etc.

Mira este ejemplo en la consola:

```
> $a = array("5"=>"Hola");
> var_dump($a);
array(1) { [5]=>"Hola" }
> $a = array_merge($a, ["9"=>"Mundo"]);
> var_dump($a);
array(2) { [0]=>"Hola", [1]=>"Mundo" } // <-- Los índices se cambiaron
```

Como posibles soluciones, podrías usar un índice tipo `"009"`, `"010"`, o también puedes hacer un [push asociativo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) de forma tradicional:

```
> $a[5] = "Stack";
> $a[7] = "Overflow";
> var_dump($a);
array(4) { [0]=>"Hola", [1]=>"Mundo", [5]=>"Stack", [7]=>"Overflow" }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @aeportugal, me ha quedado muy claro. Gracias por tu tiempo en tan bonita respuesta.
Lo resolví entonces pasando un string de un entero decimal NO válido, como "009".